# looking for more efficient 'for loop' sql

Tags: sql, for-loop, row

I need help with formatting the output for a 'for loop'.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MYPROCEDURE (MYPARAM VARCHAR2)
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE
type values_table    IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(1999);        
    MYVALUES                           values_table;

BEGIN
select subscriptionName || ', ' c.name 
BULK COLLECT INTO MYVALUES
from magazine_subscriptions ms
join customers c on ms.customer_id = c.customer_id
where ms.subscription_id > 0;

  FOR i IN 1..MYVALUES.COUNT LOOP       
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(MYVALUES(i));
  END LOOP;
END;
END;
/
```

When I run this I get repeats of subscription name.

Example:

```
Subscription bi-annual, james tills
Subscription bi-annual, jessie beckman
Subscription bi-annual, john sackman
Subscription 6-months, amelia hearts
Subscription 6-months, amanda tillman
Subscription 3-months, sally forth
Subscription 3-months, sadie hawkins
Subscription 3-months, susan beaker
```

Is there a way to get this instead?

```
Subscription bi-annual
james tills
jessie beckman
john sackman

Subscription 6-months:
amelia hearts
amanda tillman

Subscription 3-months: 
sally forth
sadie hawkins
susan hearst
```

Thank you for reading this.

Comment: You can just paste the code, selct it and press `ctrl+k`  sothat i will be formatted propely

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks like Oracle.  You can combine the names into a single string:

```
select subscriptionName, list_agg(c.name, ',') within group (order b c.name) 
from magazine_subscriptions ms join
     customers c
     on ms.customer_id = c.customer_id
where ms.subscription_id > 0
group by subscriptionName;
```

The delimiter can be anything.  This just uses a comma for illustration.